# block flow with iptables

Tags: command-line, networking, security, iptables, firewall

To block packets containing some string we use the following iptables rule:

```
iptables -I FORWARD 1 -p tcp --dport 80 -m string --string anypattern --algo bm -j DROP
```

This will block the packet containing the string "anypattern".

How to block the next packets (which did not contain the "anypattern" string) but have the same ip address of the matched packet?

is it possible to make it with ip mark ?

I tried the following mark rules but it does not work

```
iptables -I FORWARD 1 -p tcp --dport 80 -m string --string anypattern --algo bm -j MARK --set-mark 1
iptables -I FORWARD 2 -m mark --mark 1 -j DROP
```

I tried the followinf command

```
echo anypattern | nc 192.168.1.1 80
```

The traffic is blocked

Later I used the same ip and port to send another message

```
echo othermsg | nc 192.168.1.1 80
```

I expected that this request will be blocked, But it's not

Comment: You can achieve your objective using the `recent` module in iptables. I just spent way way too much time on an answer to another of your questions and do not have time now for another.

Comment: @DougSmythies link of the other question ?